# How to use GraalVM with JavaFX to compile a native image in Maven?

Tags: java, linux, maven, javafx, graalvm

I have a JavaFX project, and would like to compile it into a Linux binary using the GraalVM Java virtual machine and the associated Native-Image tool. I am using GraalVM Java 11 Version 20.1.0, and the Native Image Maven plugin, that is added through Maven, to achieve this.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.oracle.substratevm</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>19.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>sample.NewMain</mainClass>
        <imageName>sample</imageName>
        <buildArgs>
            -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=/home/user/Documents/Projects/TestProject/src/main/java/sample/reflect-config.json -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces
        </buildArgs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>native-image</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Originally, I got an error stating `Warning: Aborting stand-alone image build due to reflection use without configuration.` I used the Native Image tracing agent to generate config files for reflection,
which I pass into the compiler plugin like this:
`-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=/home/user/Documents/Projects/TestProject/src/main/java/sample/reflect-config.json -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces`

I also have stack trace exception reporting turned on.

Now, when I attempt to compile to a native image, I get the following error to do with the usage of native libraries:

```
Warning: System method java.lang.System.loadLibrary invoked at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:163)
Warning: System method java.lang.System.loadLibrary invoked at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:177)
Warning: Aborting stand-alone image build due to loading native libraries without configuration.
com.oracle.svm.hosted.FallbackFeature$FallbackImageRequest: System method java.lang.System.loadLibrary invoked at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:163)
System method java.lang.System.loadLibrary invoked at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:177)
Aborting stand-alone image build due to loading native libraries without configuration.
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FallbackFeature.afterAnalysis(FallbackFeature.java:293)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$9(NativeImageGenerator.java:741)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:70)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:741)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:538)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:451)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
```

How can I configure the use of native libraries? There is no option for this within the Native Image compiler tool, nor any mention of it that I can find anywhere.

I have managed to compile other projects with the Native Image tool, which means that this problem is JavaFX related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not work that way. You will have to use Gluons client-maven-plugin https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin for this purpose. It provides a special version of compiled Java and JavaFX libraries to make this work. Follow the instructions closely. Then it will work. I am using it on a regular basis.