# Gluon Client Maven Plugin: Which type of classes should be specified under 'reflectionList' configuration

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

In the [official documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_reflectionlist) of Gluon Client maven plugin, the 'reflectionList' section is explained as

> List of additional full qualified classes that will be added to the default reflection list, that already includes most of the JavaFX classes.

Tbh, it doesn't clearly explain what type of classes should be added in 'reflectionList'. In a pom.xml file of a [gluon sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/pushnotes/pom.xml) some of the classes in that project are not specified.

So, what kind of classes do we have to specify in 'reflectionList'?

Answer (score 1):

You only have to add classes which are loaded via reflection. This happens for example when you are using FXML. It's mostly a try and error game unless you are following a more systematic approach and use the GraalVM native-image agent.

Comment: Yes, about that, there is a new goal that you can use: `mvn client:runagent`, as documented: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_clientrunagent

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks for the link to the documentation. I hadn't seen that yet. Up to now I used the agent manually.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, controllers for FXML views created in Scene Builder. In the FXML file you specify what class should be a controller for a view generated from this file, and in that controller class you put fields and methods which are linked to elements in FXML. Sometimes, unfortunately, if you use a certain JavaFX widget in FXML you will also have to specify it on the reflection list (happened to me with `javafx.scene.control.TitledPane`).

There is way to make it more fine-grained and specify certain methods instead of all classes, but I wouldn't recomment it. Please take a look here for details: [How to solve fxml loading exceptions in compiled JavaFX project using GluonHQ client, Native Image and GraalVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527596/how-to-solve-fxml-loading-exceptions-in-compiled-javafx-project-using-gluonhq-cl)

My solution is to keep FXML simple and enrich it with additional styles, register methods on actions (unless they are straightforward, like onClick), etc., in the code, so that I don't have to deal much with reflection.